# Can't use Telerik Testing Framework from web application

Tags: c#, browser, web-applications, console

I recently starting fiddling around with the Telerik Test Framework ( http://www.telerik.com/teststudio/testing-framework ).

I used this to set up automated browser tests.
At first i used them in classical test project in Visual Studio and everything worked fine.

Next i wanted to be able to use the automated browser outside of Visual Studio. So i create a console application where i used the framework for my automated browser, and everything worked fine.

Next i wanted to create a MVC project where i used the framework for the automated browser, and everything stopped working.

It seems like that for some reason when the automated browser is called from a web application that the selected browser won't start up.

The actual code were the automated browser is started is the same for the web app and the console app. Just different starting points.

I also don't get any errors about the browser not starting up, i simply end up with a time out exception from the framework after i want to launch the browser.

Console code:

```
namespace AutomatedTests
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
             var telerik = new TelerikTests();
             telerik.TestLanguageCoockie();
        }
    }
}
```

Web application code:

```
namespace AutomatedTests.Controllers
{
    public class BrowserTestController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
             var telerikTests = new TelerikTests();
             telerikTests.TestLanguageCoockie();
        }
    }
}
```

TelerikTests code:

```
namespace AutomatedTests.Tests
{
     [TestClass]
     public class TelerikTests : BaseTest
     {
          private static Settings settings;

          public TelerikTests()
          {
               Init();
          }

          private Manager createMyManager
          {
               get
               {
                    return new Manager(settings);  // = ArtOfTest.WebAii.Core.Manager
               }
          }

          public void Init()
          {
                // Get basic settings.
                settings = GetSettings(); // = BaseTest.GetSettings();

                // Custumize away!
                settings.Web.DefaultBrowser = BrowserType.Chrome;
                settings.Web.KillBrowserProcessOnClose = true;
          }

          [TestMethod]
          public void TestLanguageCoockie()
          {
                var myManager = createMyManager;
                myManager.Start();

                myManager.LaunchNewBrowser();

                // More code to perform the actual test, but with the web app approach we never get past this. The browser doesn't start and a time out exception is thrown.

           }
       }
  }
```

EDIT: It turns out that i have this issue for every browser, except IE. But i do need it working for the other browsers as well.

Comment: I can't imagine why you would want to do this, but is the site running locally or on a remote server? The browser automation requires an interactive session.

Comment: I have it set up on my local machine and on a server. It has the same result in both cases. And the reason i'm doing this is to setup predefined automated browser testing that people can access from a web interface. Also: i don't think i fully technically understand what you mean with a interactive session.

Comment: It is odd to reference tests in another project. I don't know why it is not working locally but it will never work from a server unless someone logged into an unlocked desktop.

Comment: So you're saying that a (dedicated) account would always have to be logged in to the server to that it can use that 'interactive session' to open up the browser ? I did assume as much.

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Comment: Would you happen to know how i can get my web application to use that interactive session ? I've tried to impersonate my personal account and i was able to add a parameter saying "LogonType.Interactive" but the result is the same.

Comment: I'm sorry, I never tried it that way.

Comment: I dumped the [Quick Start Sample Code](http://docs.telerik.com/teststudio/testing-framework/getting-started#Quick-Start-Sample-Code) into a controller ActionResult and it just worked. Of course, I'm referencing the TTF directly, not going through an MS Test dll.

Comment: My code isn't that different from the quick start ( and i also use the TTF directly, i only used the MS Test in a first scenario ). But i figured i would try this aswell. And to my great suprise, this worked! As it turned out it only works for me when i use this code with IE and i previously only tested it with Chrome/Firefox. If possible could you also try this for these browser and let me know if this still works for you ?

Comment: I used chrome, so I guess I didn't use exactly the quickstart code. I'll try FF and IE when I get to work.

Comment: Extra, it does work with IE. But it doesn't show the actual browser. I assume this is because IE can work in a non interactive session. (i don't care if i see the browser or not, as long as i runs properly) I also now tried using impersonate + CreateProcessAsUser ( https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682429(v=vs.85).aspx ) But again this has the same result ( really figured that this should have worked )

Comment: You know you have to run the tests with administrative privileges when using IE right? It is not so with chrome ir FF

Comment: This confusses me greatly as IE is the only browser that works... Also the web app is run with the Network Service account. I've given it full rights to the web app folder, chrome folder, telerik folder, ... Not sure how i can give admin privileges to that account. And when i use impersonate i use my own admin account.

Comment: Maybe the IE interaction has changed, that is why I usually never tested with IE. I will try that as well. [Here is one mention of it](http://www.telerik.com/forums/ie-problem-on-windows-server-2012-r2#1ErE_af1i0ia48b3TQ9HGQ), you can google more but it could just be outdated.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134768/discussion-between-crowcoder-and-timon).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up setting up a console project + a web application. The web application contacts the console application so that it can perform all the automated browser tasks. Later it send the information back to the web app so that it can send it back to the client.